# Unclear xcode interface builder feature - Beginner

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

When one uses the Interface Builder to arrange the UI Components, there is an option where you have to click to resize or arrange all UI components (buttons, labels, etc.) to fit the view. What is this feature called? And how can you do this programmatically?

Comment: your question is not clear. What do you want to do? do you want to automate interface changes? if not what do you mean by programatically? ALSO do you want your UI elements to fill the window? or ...

Comment: He's thinking of CGRect. To position UIView components on the screen and size them. Look into the frame property of UIView Objects and CGRect/CGRectMake(). CGRect takes four parameters origin.x, origin.y frame.size.width, frame.size.height. Buttons,Labels and many of the components all inherit from UIView. Take a look at the Doc's.http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW6  Or possibly the Auto-Resizing Mask for placement of components during orientation changes.

Comment: exactly what i need. But since i have created all ui components by code, i am unable to use the option provided in the interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the `autoresizingMask` property for a `UIView`.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6)

Comment: I guess. or is it `AutoresizeSubview`. How can i do this ?